# read text file in python and extract specific value in each line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that each line of it is as follows:

```
 n:1 mse_avg:8.46 mse_y:12.69 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:38.86 psnr_y:37.10 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf 
 n:2 mse_avg:12.20 mse_y:18.30 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:37.27 psnr_y:35.51 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf
```

I need to read each line extract psnr_y and its value in a matrix. does python have any other functions for reading a text file? I need to extract psnr_y from each line. I have a matlab code for this, but I need a python code and I am not familiar with functions in python. could you please help me with this issue?
this is the matlab code:

```
opt = {'Delimiter',{':',' '}};
fid = fopen('data.txt','rt');
nmc = nnz(fgetl(fid)==':');
frewind(fid);
fmt = repmat('%s%f',1,nmc);
tmp = textscan(fid,fmt,opt{:});
fclose(fid);
fnm = [tmp{:,1:2:end}];
out = cell2struct(tmp(:,2:2:end),fnm(1,:),2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex like below:

```
import re

with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    a = f.readlines()
    pattern = r'psnr_y:([\d.]+)'
    for line in a:
        print(re.search(pattern, line)[1])
```

This code will return only psnr_y's value. you can remove [1] and change it with [0] to get the full string like "psnr_y:37.10".
If you want to assign it into a list, the code would look like this:

```
import re

a_list = []

with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    a = f.readlines()
    pattern = r'psnr_y:([\d.]+)'
    for line in a:
        a_list.append(re.search(pattern, line)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

use regular expression

```
r'psnr_y:([\d.]+)'
```

on each line read

and extract `match.group(1)` from the result

if needed convert to float: `float(match.group(1))`

Answer (score 1):

Since I hate regex, I would suggest:

```py
s = 'n:1 mse_avg:8.46 mse_y:12.69 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:38.86 psnr_y:37.10 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf \nn:2 mse_avg:12.20 mse_y:18.30 mse_u:0.00 mse_v:0.00 psnr_avg:37.27 psnr_y:35.51 psnr_u:inf psnr_v:inf' 
lst = s.split('\n')
out = []
for line in lst:
  psnr_y_pos = line.index('psnr_y:')
  next_key = line[psnr_y_pos:].index(' ')
  psnr_y = line[psnr_y_pos+7:psnr_y_pos+next_key]
  out.append(psnr_y)
print(out)
```

`out` is a list of the values of `psnr_y` in each line.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple answer with no need to import additional modules, you could try:

```
rows = []
with open("my_file", "r") as f:
    for row in f.readlines():
        value_pairs = row.strip().split(" ")
        print(value_pairs)
        values = {pair.split(":")[0]: pair.split(":")[1] for pair in value_pairs}
        print(values["psnr_y"])
        rows.append(values)

print(rows)
```

This gives you a list of dictionaries (basically JSON structure but with python objects).
This probably won't be the fastest solution but the structure is nice and you don't have to use regex

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input():
    row = dict([s.split(':') for s in re.findall('[\S]+:[\S]+', line)])
    print(row['psnr_y'])
```

To verify,

```
python script_name.py < /path/to/your/dataset.txt
```